# How to substitute string in {} in "find (...) -exec (...) {} \;" bash command?

Tags: bash, find

How can I substitute a string in `{}` as found by bash's ´find´?

For instance I would like `?` below to substitute "in" by "out":

`find . -name "*.in" -exec python somescript.py {} ? \;`

i.e. to execute for all "*.in" files

`python somescript.py somefile.in somefile.out`

Comment: you could also modify somescript.py if it makes sense.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`find` doesn't have a substitution feature. You need to call a shell.

```
find . -name "*.in" -exec sh -c 'python somescript.py "$0" "${0%.in}.out"' {} \;
```

`$0` is the file name, `${0%.in}` removes the `.in` suffix.

Alternatively, in bash (but not in plain sh), run `shopt -s globstar` to enable recursive directory expansion (and `shopt -s nullglob` if there's a risk that there won't be any matching `.in` file) and use a `for` loop instead of `find`.

```
for x in **/*.in; do
  python somescript.py "$x" "${x%.in}.out"
done
```

Comment: maybe also `shopt -s nullglob` or `[[ -e $x ]]||continue`

Comment: How can I write that with a substitution? I tried "${0/in/out} but I get "Bad substitution" error.

Comment: @jul There's no substitution in sh. In bash this would run without an error, but it wouldn't produce the right result in general (e.g. it would turn `large.inputs/foo.in` into `large.outputs/foo.in`).

Comment: Ok, this works with `bash`. As you commented, I just need to be careful about cases with several occurences of the pattern to be substituted.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`Brace Expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion):

```
find . -name "*.in" -exec bash -c 'python script.py "${0%.*}"{.in,.out}' {} \;
```

Using [`Shell Parameter Expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
find . -name "*.in" -exec bash -c 'python script.py "${0} ${0/.in/.out}"' {} \;
```

**Result**:

```
python script.py somefile.in somefile.out
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, all the built-in tools were a bit cumbersome to use (did I get the shell quoting right? will it do the right thing? can I easily preview changes?).

A few years ago, I wrote [rpt](https://thp.io/2016/rpt/) that will take its command line parameters, open a text editor (to let you edit the file names) and then run a command (default `mv`) on the old and new filenames.

Recently, I took this a step further, here's `fea` (For Each Argument):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# fea: For Each Argument
# https://thp.io/2019/rpt-and-fea.html

import sys, shlex, re

_, cmd, *args = sys.argv

print('\n'.join(re.sub(r'[{](.)([^}]*?)(\1)([^}]*?)(\1)[}]',
    lambda m: shlex.quote(re.sub(m.group(2), m.group(4), arg)),
    cmd).replace('{}', shlex.quote(arg)) for arg in args))
```

The following replacements happen:

```
{} -> insert arg
{/regex/replacement/} -> run re.sub(regex, replacement) on the arg,
                         you can pick any character for "/", as long
                         as it appears at the start, middle and end
                         (to separate the regex from the replacement)
```

Some use cases:

```
# Create backup files
fea "cp {} {}.bak" *.py

# Encode WAV files with oggenc
fea "oggenc {} -o {/wav$/ogg/}" *.wav

# Decode MP3 files with mpg123
fea "mpg123 -w {/mp3$/wav/} {}" *.mp3

# Render markdown documents to HTML
fea "markdown {} > {/md$/html/}" *.md

# Fancy replacement
fea "markdown {} > {#input/(.*).md#output/\1.html#}" input/*.md

# As mentioned above, note that you need to pipe the
# fea output into a shell to execute the command
fea "cp {} {}.bak" *.py | sh -e -x
```

Your use case can be covered like this:

```
find . -name '*.in' -print0 | xargs -0 fea "python somescript.py {} {/in$/out/}"
```

Or if the files are just in the current folder:

```
fea "python somescript.py {} {/in$/out/}" *.in
```

Or if you are using `zsh` with [recursive globbing](https://lorenzod8n.wordpress.com/2007/05/10/recursive-globbing-in-zsh/):

```
fea "python somescript.py {} {/in$/out/}" **/*.in
```

If you are happy with the commands it displays, just pipe its output into `sh -e -x` (or `bash` or whatever) to execute them.

While it's possible to make a `for` loop with the shell (or any of the parameter/variable expansions), shell quoting and escaping is so hard to get right (for me), the `fea` tool makes sure it also works with weird names:

```
touch 'some$weird "filename.py'
touch 'and !! more.py'
touch 'why oh why?.py'
touch "this is ridiculous'.py"
fea "cp {} {}.bak" *.py | sh -e -x
```

See [rpt and fea blog post](https://thp.io/2019/rpt-and-fea.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, just modify `somescript.py` to take care of creating the output filename (it's easier to do in Python than in shell, as there are no special characters that might be interpreted in some way):

```
find . -name '*.in' -exec python somescript.py {} .out \;
```

With the start of the script:

```
import sys, os
inputfilename = sys.argv[1]
outputfilename = os.path.splitext(inputfilename)[0] + sys.argv[2]

# ...
```

Of course you could hardcode `.out` and drop that parameter, too.

If you can't modify somescript.py for some reason, you could easily create a wrapper script that takes care of calling `somescript.py` the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `bash -c` command with the `find`command:

```
find -name "*.in" -exec bash -c 'python somescript.py "$1" "$(dirname "$1")/$(basename "$1" .in).out"' _ {} \;
```

The filename `{}` found is given to `bash` as `$1` argurment.

The command `basename` removes the extension, `dirname` keeps the pathname.

Comment: Here `basename` doesn't work: it removes the directory part, but the directory parts are important.

Comment: or `"${1/%.in/.out}"` or shorter `"${1%.in}.out"`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul No, that would change e.g. `large.inputs/foo.in` to `large.outputs/foo.in`. To strip a suffix, use `${1%.in}`.

Comment: @Gilles thanks for your feedback but `%` after `/` ensures the pattern to be at the end but then i realized that replacement was not needed

Answer (score 0):

An easy-to-read way would be this one:

```
find -name "*.in" | while read file; do
 python somescript.py $file ${file/.in/.out}
done
```