# How to execute a command on multiple files with different extensions on the shell?

Tags: shell

I would like to execute a command with the file names as parameter on all files in a directory with different file extensions. I tried this:

```
for i in *.jpg *.docx *.gdi; 
 do 
  mycommand dosth -i "$i" -o "${i%.*}.myext"; 
 done
```

But if one of the file extensions does not exist in the folder I get an error saying "file not found". How do I have to change the script?

Comment: What shell are you using? POSIX-compliant shells treat a non-matching string as a literal string, while `zsh` raises an error immediately if a pattern doesn't match. Many shells have an option for ignoring unmatched patterns, but that's not part of the POSIX specification.

Comment: I use this in a docker: 

FROM debian:10-slim
...
ENTRYPOINT for i in *.jpg *.docx *.gdi; 
 do 
  mycommand dosth -i "$i" -o "${i%.*}.myext"; 
 done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Debian uses `dash`, there is no option for ignoring unmatched patterns. You can distinguish between a match result and an unmatched pattern by checking if a file named `$i` exists. If it does not, then it obviously was not the result of pathname expansion (which only produces existing files, race conditions aside.)

```
for i in *.jpg *.docx *.gdi
do 
    [ -e "$i" ] || continue  # E.g., if $i == "*.jpg" after no JPG files were found
    mycommand dosth -i "$i" -o "${i%.*}.myext"
done
```

---

In a Dockerfile, as the entire command has to be on one logical line, semicolons are necessary:

```
ENTRYPOINT for i in *.jpg *.docx *.gdi; do \
     [ -e "$i" ] || continue; \
     mycommand dosth -i "$i" -o "${i%.*}.myext"; \
    done
```

Comment: I think there is a ";" missing after continue? But it seems to work!

Comment: You only need `;` to separate commands on the same physical line. The `;` terminating the `mycommand` line is allowed but unnecessary.

Comment: (Though in the context of a Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` command, yes, you do need the `;`.)

Comment: Okay, this answers my question. Thank you very much. As a bonus: my I ask how to skip a "myext" file if it exists? But this is really a bonus. Thank you very much. This will be part of an open source docker container. =)

Comment: Asked a new question regarding the "skip existing file" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68682632/how-to-skip-a-file-in-a-for-in-shell-loop-if-it-already-exists

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [find](/questions/tagged/find) to search for [multiple extensions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/how-to-use-find-command-to-search-for-multiple-extensions) like so:

```sh
find . -type f \( -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.gdi -o -iname \*. docx \) -exec mycommand {} \;
```

The `-exec` can be altered with some more parameters if needed.
<sup>[How to run find -exec?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec%3E)</sup>

---

Based on the [commends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68682040/how-to-execute-a-command-on-multiple-files-with-different-extensions-on-the-shel/68682129#comment121378734_68682129), a solution thats spawns a shell so we can use substitution:

```sh
find . -type f \( -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.gdi -o -iname \*. docx \) -exec sh -c 'mycommand dosth -i "$0" -o "${0%.*}.myext"; ' {} \;
```

<sup>[How to substitute string in {} in "find (...) -exec (...) {} \;" bash command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50406662/how-to-substitute-string-in-in-find-exec-bash-command)</sup>

Comment: This looks easy and I understand this. But how do I use the filename in "mycommand" like in my current solution?

Comment: `{}` is a placeholder representing the currently found file, passed as an argument to `mycommand`.

Comment: I tried but failed here: "${i%.*}.myext";  

This would be ${{}%.*}.myext but fails. How do I remove the extension from {}? But the solution is really nice!

Comment: Please see my edit @Marc. I'd recommend spawning a new shell so we can use variable substitution as normal.

Comment: Ah, for each of the found files with "find" you make a new shell and use the old command. Neat.

Comment: Yea, we pass the `{}` (path) to the new shell, so we can use `$0` as normal. Could be somehow 'slow' if you're processing a lot of files, because we'll spawn a shell every time. But if you're not concerned about speed (not that much files) this is a neat solution.

Comment: I really like this answer and learned a lot. But it is a new solution and the answer above with the "skip" answers the inital question.