# How to skip a file in a "for in" shell loop if a file with another extension already exists?

Tags: shell

I loop through all files in a folder with a specific extension:

```
for i in *.ext1 *.ext2 *.ext3; 
  do 
   [ -e "$i" ] || continue 
   mycommand -i "$i" -o "${i%.*}.myext"; 
  done
```

How do I skip existing files with the "myext" extension of the same name?

Comment: BTW, since you've got a `;` at the end of the `for`, you don't need a linebreak before the `do`. (Similarly, because there's a linebreak at the end of `mycommand`, you don't need a semicolon before the `done`).

Answer (score 2):

If ksh extensions are available (as in bash/zsh/etc):

```
[[ -e ${i%.*}.myext ]] && continue
```

...or, in keeping with your more POSIX-y existing code:

```
[ -e "${i%.*}.myext" ] && continue
```